# I have a question, this is alredy working and want's to make this to do a comparative betwen an db in acccess

Tags: sql-server, triggers

So well after some changes i have this but stills have the question about if this will send data from diferent tables to anoter diferent table. NOTE
this is alredy Working and is doing it's work very well deon be hestiating and a bully this works.

```
USE [ComercialSP]      -------------- you need to inititate your db were will be this 
    GO
    /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[addNewProduct]    Script Date: 12/16/2021 12:26:07 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    -- =============================================
    -- Author:      <Author,,Name>
    -- Create date: <Create Date,,>
    -- Description: <Description,,>
    -- =============================================
    
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ADDallProduct] ON [dbo].[orgProduct] -----first you need to create into a table in a DB
    AFTER INSERT                   --this is only for an 'after insert'
    AS
    
     DECLARE                                             -------- declaration of var's
            @Component NVARCHAR(40),
            @Component2 NVARCHAR(150),
            @Component3 NVARCHAR(150),
            @CompaqiID BIGINT,
            @Desc NVARCHAR(50),
            @Dept NVARCHAR(15),
            @Cata NVARCHAR(50),
            @Cost INT = 234
    BEGIN                                                  -------- end of a dec
    SET NOCOUNT ON
      SELECT @Component = inserted.ProductName FROM INSERTED WHERE Category1 = 'Tela' and Category2 <> 'Yarns'  ---- for a component we need a condition who will separate thhe thinks we need and in what DB is be inserted
      SELECT @Component2 = inserted.ProductName FROM INSERTED WHERE Category1 = 'Tela' and Category2 = 'Yarns' or Category1 <> 'Tela' ---- this to
      SELECT @Dept = inserted.Category1 FROM INSERTED     --------- and we need to make some var's  habiable for insert in te kye's for the db in this case @Dept, @cata, @CompiaquiID, and also @component, and @Component2
      SELECT @Cata = inserted.Category2 FROM INSERTED
      SELECT @CompaqiID = inserted.ProductID FROM INSERTED
    
      IF (@Component IS NOT NULL ) -----------we need a condition IF for this cause we want mistakes on code 
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Quality_be.dbo.[FabComponents t]    -------- inseertion in what db we want
            (Component,[Desc],Cata,CompaqiID)           --------the fields name of the db
    
        VALUES
            (@Component,@Desc,@Cata,@CompaqiID)     ------ and what var's we need insert
    
        END    --------  the end of this IF
      ELSE -------------- a ELSE for the other condition 
        BEGIN      ------------ the BEGIN for initiate other condition 
    
        INSERT INTO Purchasing_be.dbo.[FabComponents t]           -----------where you will insert this
            (Component,[Desc],Cata,Dept,CompaqiID,CostAcc)         -------------   the var's we'il need for this field's into this db 
    
        VALUES
            (@Component2,@Desc,@Cata,@Dept,@CompaqiID,@Cost)      --------------- and what var's we will need for this db  
    
        END    ---------------end of this condition
    END  

  ----------------- end of this trigger
```

so this end-s as this, this is alredy working the only think i want its, before insert do a comparative to a db named Quality_be, and this is enlaced to access

Comment: There is a lot wrong with the above. you `DECLARE` variables before you define the type of `TRIGGER` (in this case `AFTER INSERT`). You *assume* that your `INSERT` will only ever contain 1 row; this is wrong, it can contain 0+. You try to assign the variable with undefined column names. You use `==` which isn't an operator in T-SQL. You use `&&` which isn't an operator in SQL Server. You try to use variables like they are replacements for objects. You don't state *what* you want to `INSERT`. Everything is *before* the `AS` keyword. ... You seem to lack fundamental understanding of T-SQL here.

Comment: The problems are also not even limited to my prior comment, there are *more* issues, I just ran out of space for characters.

Comment: I change to this but i don't know if this will work, so i have a mmistake line in this   "()"  and  this "," character, so how i can make it?

Comment: i have the mistakes on this line into the coma and parentesys SELECT (dbo.orgProduct.ProducName,  dbo.orgProduct.Category1, dbo.orgProduct.Category2)

Comment: [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using sql server trigger syntax would be like this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ NoYarnsH ] ON Purchasing_be.dbo.orgProduct
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Quiality_be.dbo.FabComponents_t
    SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE YOUR_COLUMN IN ('Tela', 'Yarns')
END
```

Comment: So if someone puts a new income this will be in the other DB?

    CREATE TRIGGER [ NoYarnsH ] ON ComercialISP.dbo.orgProduct
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Quiality_be.dbo.FabComponents_t
    SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE Category1  IN ('Tela') & Category2 IN ('Yarns')
    END
o this will take all of the resulsts?, im ask because the DB has more of these and i only whants to send te new ones, not all.

Comment: if you have a lot of value that should be equal to your column you can add it in the IN statement, SQL SERVER does not take & as AND. so your query would be `Category1 = 'Tela' AND Category2 = 'Yarns'`.

Comment: Take this i will calificate you this is the correct answer for this

Comment: I change to this but i don't know if this will work, so i have a mmistake line in this "()" and this "," character, so how i can make it?

Comment: i have the mistakes on this line into the coma and parentesys SELECT (dbo.orgProduct.ProducName, dbo.orgProduct.Category1, dbo.orgProduct.Category2)